# Multiple instances of DataNucleus' JDO in same JVM

Tags: java, jvm, instance, jdo, datanucleus

How many instances of DataNucleus' JDO implementation can run at the same time in the same JVM? I have tried to launch two and it seems that one dies silently. Is this a bug or is this to be expected?

Comment: What do you mean "instances of DataNucleus" ? How many PMFs ? with the same datastore or different? If you say something "dies" then it has a log and leaves log entries

Comment: Yes, I mean how many PMFs can be started together with different set of properties. What I noticed is that the second does not seem to be alive (two separated thread try to access one of them separately, but one thread is doing nothing).

Comment: I start several at once no problem ... in fact for the DN facility JDOReplicator to work it has to have two. Suggest you debug your PMFs using the log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. My issue was caused by a coding issue.